# Capturing a still of a video with brightcove on iOS

Tags: ios, brightcove

I have a bright cove player playing a video and I would like to either take a screen grab of the video or request a still of the image in some way. It doesn't really matter at what time, it's just for an arbitrary thumbnail of the video.

Answer (score 0):

The `BCOVVideo` class has a video still URL as a property:

```
video.properties[kBCOVCatalogJSONKeyVideoStillUrl];
```